# Understanding map coordinates in 7 Days to Die

Tags: 7-days-to-die

I've been playing 7D2D for a little while now, but only recently came across the console, and noticed that certain things happen at specific coordinates, like an airdrop. I know the triple is (X,Y,Z) where X is East/West, Z is North/South, and Y is height from bedrock.

The thing I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around is that some of these coordinates are in the negative. I read that the X coordinate is "West to East", does that mean that a negative X value is West of the origin, and a positive X value is East, etc.?

Same for North South... it says "South to North" -- does that mean -Z is South of origin, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some research, and learned about the debug console (bit of a newb of creative mode) so I was able to play around with teleporting to various locations to test this...

For reference, teleporting to 0,0 was a good start -- middle of the hub city of course.
From there, -100,-100 took me to the southwest, then -200,-200 took me even further southwest, so it appears I was correct. -X is to the West, and +X is to the East, same for -Z (South) and +Z (North).

Didn't realize the debug console even existed, but it definitely is a cool tool for learning some of the game mechanics.